# Convert middle substring to "*"

Tags: java, regex

I have a string `String email="rachitgulati26@gmail.com"` so its length is 24.

I want result like rachit************il.com.That means 1/4 of initial same and last 1/4 same.

Just want to convert 1/2 from middle to * with the help of regEX.

Thanks

Comment: That's a nice example! Where is your problem?

Comment: Problem is i dont know how to solve it with regEx .

Comment: You could try to use a for loop.

Comment: So you mean it is not possible with regEx ?

Comment: we can get the length of string and easily calculate 1/2 and 1/4 of it.

Comment: Getting length of string and calculating is outside the regex solution :)

Comment: oops sry i guess then i asked it in wrong way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
"rachitgulati26@gmail.com".replaceAll("(?<=.{5}).(?=.{5})", "*");
```

this will replace all characters to `*` apart from the first and last 5.

In response to your question, you could make this flexible like this:

```
String email = "rachitgulati26@gmail.com";
int i = email.length() / 4;
email = email.replaceAll("(?<=.{" + i + "}).(?=.{" + i + "})", "*");
```

Just a word of warning, if you were to start using this in production code, you probably want to create a way of caching these regexes, based on the value of `i`. This way is for demonstration of the pattern only, and will compile a regex `Pattern` each time it is used.

Comment: can we change 5 to length/4 ?

Comment: @squiroid I have changed the code, so that it can be made flexible

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to create a string of `'*'`s that is the correct length, then concatenate on the surrounding parts of the original string. That way you don't have to do any looping:

```
public static String starize(String str){
    char[] middle = new char[str.length()/2];
    Arrays.fill(middle, '*');
    return str.substring(0, str.length()/4) 
           + String.copyValueOf(middle) 
           + str.substring(3 * str.length() / 4);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could convert to char array, process and convert back to String:

```
String email = "rachitgulati26@gmail.com";
char[] a = email.toCharArray();
for (int i = 0, j = a.length >> 2; i < a.length >> 1; i++, j++)
    a[j] = '*';
email = new String(a);
```

Result:

```
rachit************il.com
```

You can't identify the middle of a string using a single regular expression unless the lengths have a finite number of values.

Comment: I dont want for loop thanks i m looking for regEx :-)